# I am trying to fetch the profile uid, the specific one the user has made. It is fetching all the profile uids in the database

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching the uid that the user has made like I have 2000 uids in my database But here I am trying to fetch the specific one they made like suppose I have made this uid "8w17478-fsdnfh-sdnmfjlsn-fsdlfdfs" and I have many uids In my database not one And I am trying to fetch the specific one that is made by the user this one "8w17478-fsdnfh-sdnmfjlsn-fsdlfdfs" not all the uids made by different users it is just fetching like all the uids made by all the different users not the current user. The database is Firestore database

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  Card,
  Typography,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemPrefix,
  ListItemSuffix,
  Chip,
  Input,
} from "@material-tailwind/react";
import {
  UserCircleIcon,
  InboxIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import {
  SearchIcon
} from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import { db } from '../firebase/firebaseConfig';
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const Sidebar = () => {
  const [userProfiles, setUserProfiles] = useState([]);
  const auth = getAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserProfiles = async () => {
      try {
        const profileCollectionRef = collection(db, 'profiles');
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(profileCollectionRef);

        const profilesData = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          profilesData.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
        });

        setUserProfiles(profilesData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user profiles:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchUserProfiles();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Card className="h-[calc(100vh-2rem)] w-full max-w-[20rem] p-4 shadow-xl shadow-blue-gray-900/5 text-gray-500">
      <div className="mb-2 flex items-center gap-4 p-4 font-bricolage-grotesque">
        <img src="Logo.svg" alt="brand" className="h-8 w-8" />
        <Typography variant="h5" color="blue-gray">
          Sidebar
        </Typography>
      </div>
      <div className="p-2">
        <Input className="rounded-md w-[16.6rem]" icon={<SearchIcon className="h-5 focus:none pt-2 pl-2 w-5" />} />
      </div>
      <List>
        <hr className="my-2 border-blue-gray-50" />
        <Link to="/Offers" className="ml-1 no-underline text-black">
          <ListItem>
            <ListItemPrefix>
              <InboxIcon className="h-5 w-5" />
            </ListItemPrefix>
            <p className="ml-1 text-black font-gowun-dodum text-[1.5rem] ">Offers</p>
            <ListItemSuffix>
              <Chip value="14" size="sm" variant="ghost" color="blue-gray" className="rounded-full ml-1" />
            </ListItemSuffix>
          </ListItem>
        </Link>

        {userProfiles.map((profile) => (
          <Link key={profile.id} to={`/Profile/${profile.id}` || '/CreateProfile'} className="ml-1 mt-4 no-underline text-black">
            <ListItem>
              <ListItemPrefix>
                <UserCircleIcon className="h-5 w-5" />
              </ListItemPrefix>
              <button className="font-gowun-dodum text-[1.5rem] bg-white text-black">{"Your Profile" || "CreateProfile"}</button>
            </ListItem>
          </Link>
        ))}

        <Link to="/Settings" className="ml-1 no-underline text-black">
          <ListItem>
            <ListItemPrefix>
              <img src="cog.svg" className="h-5 w-5" />
            </ListItemPrefix>
            <p className=" font-gowun-dodum text-[1.5rem] ml-1 text-black">Settings</p>
          </ListItem>
        </Link>
      </List>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

CreateProfile.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { db } from '../firebase/firebaseConfig';
import { doc, getDoc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const defaultProfileData = {
  name: '',
  about: '',
  previousOccupation: '',
  email: '',
  social: '',
  portfolio_website: '',
  githublink: '',
};

export default function CreateProfile() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState(defaultProfileData);
  const [profileExists, setProfileExists] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const userName = uuidv4();

    const checkProfile = async () => {
      try {
        const profileRef = doc(db, 'profiles', userName);
        const profileSnapshot = await getDoc(profileRef);
        if (profileSnapshot.exists()) {
          setProfileExists(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error checking user profile:', error);
      }
    };

    checkProfile();
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const userName = uuidv4(); 
      const profileRef = doc(db, 'profiles', userName);
      await setDoc(profileRef, profileData);
      console.log('User profile created successfully.');
      navigate(`/profile/${userName}`); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating user profile:', error);
    }
  };

  if (profileExists) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className='w-[24rem] mx-auto'>
      <h1 className='text-2xl font-semibold mb-4'>Create Your Profile</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {/* Name */}
        <div className='mb-4'>
          <label htmlFor='name' className='block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-2'>
            Your Name
          </label>
          <input
            type='text'
            id='name'
            className='w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-300'
            value={profileData.name}
            onChange={(e) => setProfileData({ ...profileData, name: e.target.value })}
            maxLength={30}
          />
        </div>

        {/* About Me */}
        <div className='mb-4'>
          <label htmlFor='about' className='block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-2'>
            About Me
          </label>
          <textarea
            id='about'
            className='w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-300'
            rows='4'
            value={profileData.about}
            onChange={(e) => setProfileData({ ...profileData, about: e.target.value })}
            maxLength={200}
          />
        </div>

        {/* Previous Occupation */}
        <div className='mb-4'>
          <label htmlFor='previousOccupation' className='block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-2'>
            Previous Occupation
          </label>
          <input
            maxLength={50}
            type='text'
            id='previousOccupation'
            className='w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-300'
            value={profileData.previousOccupation}
            onChange={(e) => setProfileData({ ...profileData, previousOccupation: e.target.value })}
          />
        </div>

        {/* Email */}
        <div className='mb-4'>
          <label htmlFor='email' className='block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-2'>
            Email
          </label>
          <input
            maxLength={50}
            type='email'
            id='email'
            className='w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-300'
            value={profileData.email}
            onChange={(e) => setProfileData({ ...profileData, email: e.target.value })}
          />
        </div>

        {/* Social Links */}
        <div className='mb-4'>
          <label htmlFor='social' className='block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-2'>
            Social Links
          </label>
          <input
            maxLength={80}
            type='text'
            id='social'
            className='w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-300'
            value={profileData.social}
            onChange={(e) => setProfileData({ ...profileData, social: e.target.value })}
          />
        </div>

        <div className='mb-4'>
          <label htmlFor='portfolio_website' className='block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-2'>
            Portfolio Website
          </label>
          <input
            maxLength={80}
            type='text'
            id='portfolio_website'
            className='w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-300'
            value={profileData.portfolio_website}
            onChange={(e) => setProfileData({ ...profileData, portfolio_website: e.target.value })}
          />
          </div>
          <div className='mb-4'>
            <label htmlFor='portfolio_website' className='block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-2'>
              Github Link
            </label>
            <input
              maxLength={80}
              type='text'
              id='githublink'
              className='w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-300'
              value={profileData.githublink}
              onChange={(e) => setProfileData({ ...profileData, githublink: e.target.value })}
            />
          </div>

          <button
            type='submit'
            className='w-full py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-600'
          >
            Create Profile
          </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Firebase

## Rules

[image: firebase rules]

## The DATABASE

[image: All DATA]

## Result

[image: Problem!]

Comment: I had to scratch my head a bit because his question wanders around. It would be more clear from the get-go if you started with
1. My system has X id's per user
2. I would like to get specific ID Y
3. My database query is giving me all the ID's
4. Note whether any of the IDs are autogenerated.

Comment: These are actually auto generated I use a library called "uuid4".

Comment: I don't want a specific ID rather I want the ID of the user. How do I make you understand this? OK here I want the ID of THE USER who signed in and filled in the details in createprofile.js, not the user who is currently viewing the profile but the user whose profile is or who owns the profile

Comment: and 1 ID per user.

Comment: can anyone give me the solution to this problem?!

Comment: The question is a bit unclear so let me try this: whenever a user is created in Firebase, they are assigned a unique id called the `user id` and in code it's `uid`. When a user authenticates (e.g. logs in), the `currentUser` var has a property `uid`. So, for example, to get the current users uid it would be `let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser.uid` (in Swift as an example, all of the SDK's have something similar). See the documentation [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users).

Comment: To add more clarity to my comment above. When a user authenticates, the `currentUser` property will be populated and you're know that users uid, so then their profile can be directly fetched as long as the documentId's stored in profiles are users uid's. e.g. no need for a query since the documentId matches the uid.